# Reading a file and looping through it and adding each element to its own index in php

Tags: php, python, arrays, indexing

i am trying to figure out how to read items from a file and adding them to a PHP array so i can access and compare values in PHP.

In python i can do this:

```
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()
            data.append({'name': line[0], 'address': line[1])}
```

But i dont have a clue how to do this in PHP, tried looking it up on google but no dice, need help

Comment: `$data[] = array("name"=>$line[0], "address"=>$line[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = array();
$file = file('filename', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($file AS $line){
    if(strpos($line,'#')===0){ continue; }
    $tmp = explode(' ',$line,2);
    $data[] = array("name"=>$tmp[0], "address"=>$tmp[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, and say i wanted to ignore lines that start with "#" while iterating through the file, what would i need to add and where? i tried browsing if there was a  | FILE_SKIP_# but no luck :)

Comment: Before explode: `if(strpos($line,'#')===0){ continue; }`

Comment: What does the "2" at the end of explode mean? Do i need to increase this number incase i want to add more indexes into the array?

Comment: To have rest of line in address even if it contains space. "If `limit` is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string." [man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)